# How to find the perimeter of a fractal?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I find the perimeter of the cantor dust fractal, in explicit form?
So far I have found the recursive formula to be: $$a_n= a_{n-1}*(\frac{4}{3})$$ $$n>1$$

I got this: $$(4, 5.33, 7.11, 9.48)$$ as the answer for the perimeter for the first four sequences.At this point I need to find the explicit formula and possibly compute the perimeter as n approaches infinity.

EDIT: I think I found the explicit formula if someone could double check my work $$4^{n}*\frac{1}{3}^{n-1}$$

Image of cantor dust fractal:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ1wy.png

Comment: How do you get that formula? For me it looks like the perimeter of step $n$ of the construction would be $4\cdot(4/3)^n$, if you divide each side of a square into equal thirds at each step.

Comment: It might be more fun to divide each square into 4×4 subsquares and keep the four corner ones. Then the perimeter of _every_ step is 4.

Comment: I redid the problem, does this look right to you?